# How to create ComboBox like UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm trying to build an usercontrol wich is able to take elements from XAML like this:

```
            <ComboBox >
                <ComboBoxItem />
                <ComboBoxItem />
                <ComboBoxItem />
            </ComboBox>
```

In the `ComboBox`, you can just add the Items between the `ComboBox` tags, and I would like to copy this, but I don't know where to start.

Finished it should look like this:

```
    <cis:ReportControl Grid.Row="3">
            <cis:ReportItem />
    </cis:ReportControl>
```

In the `cis:ReportControl`, there are some `Button`s and a `ComboBox`, and basically I only want to feed the `ComboBox` with Items.

The Report Item is just a `ComboBoxItem` with some extra properties.

**Edit:**

I've implemented it according to @Snowbears answer, but the problem now is that the control has itself as an item. 
I think this is because I have some content, and by defining the `ContentProperty` to my `ComboBox`, it is redirected into the Box.
What can I do to avoid this?

**Edit II:**

It fully works now with this:

```
    private ItemCollection reportItems;
    public ItemCollection ReportItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (reportItems == null)
            {
                reportItems = this.ComboBoxReports.Items;
            }
            return reportItems;
        }
    }
```

with the `[ContentProperty("ReportItems")]` Attribute. ComboBoxReports is the ComboBox in the Control, and I had to inherit from `ItemsControl` to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should create property in your UserControl which will expose something implementing `IList` interface. Let's say this property will be named `ReportItems`. This property should not have setter and it should be initialized in UserControl itself either in constructor in by field initialization on backing field.
2. UserControl should be marked with [ContentProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx) attribute with your property name (`ReportItems`)
3. Internal combobox should have it's `ItemsSource` bound to UserControl's `ReportItems` property

Answer (score 0):

if you look for `How to Create Your own Control`, You must look for two things:

> 1. [Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx) [1](http://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html) or [User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163421.aspx) [1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UserControl.aspx) (it's depend on your [need](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/data-misc/xml/article.php/c12521))
> 2. [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) (use them in control)

I think you might need to use Custom-Control. Also you can inherit your Custom-Control from `ComboBox` or other Controls.